# VM to VirtualBox converted image - Could not find a storage controller named 'SCSI Controller' error

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, conversion, scsi

I converted a VMDK to an ovf image using ovftool. The VMDK had a SCSI disk. Now post conversion Virtual Box isn't able to import it - it gets the error

```
Could not find a storage controller named 'SCSI Controller'.
```

This page has a solution - https://ctors.net/2014/07/17/vmware_to_virtualbox

- Boot the VM
- Uninstall vmware tools
- Shutdown
- Edit VM settings -> remove the HD
- Edit the_machine.vmdk
- change ddb.adapterType from "buslogic" or "lsilogic" to "ide"
- Edit VM settings -> add an HD, type IDE from existing file the_machine.vmdk
- Boot the VM
- Shutdown

However, how do I do the edit the vmdk file - it's a binary file, right? And it's a multigb file.

Anyone know a better way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Is your virtual hard disk partitioned into split virtual disks, as I have had configured my virtual machines? If your answer to the question is "yes", you're in luck. Actually, the `.vmdk` file is a text file chock-full of configuration settings for the virtual hard disk.

Just open `<your VM name>.vmdk` file in the VM's folder (make sure it is small in size, has an extension named `.vmdk` and the file type is `Virtual Machine Disk Format`) in any proper text editor (i.e. any third-party text editor not named Notepad) and look for these lines below:

```
# The Disk Data Base 
#DDB
```

Usually the ddb.adapterType setting is the first line below the two lines described above. Change the right side value to `"ide"`, save the file and you're set to proceed to further steps.

Example:
`ddb.adapterType = "lsilogic"` to `ddb.adapterType = "ide"`